# Godot: How to recognize the type of a built-in type?

Tags: godot, gdscript

In GDScript the `is` keyword can be used to check whether a value is an instance of a type:

```
if (input is SomeClass):
    # this works fine
```

But you can't do that for primitive "built-in" types like strings:

```
if (input is String):
   # this won't compile
```

That gives me a "Parser Error: misplaced expression, misplaced: Built-In Type"

So how do you check if an input is a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it!

You can't use `is` for primitives, but instead there's a `typeof` function:

```
if typeof(input) == TYPE_STRING
```

The value there is a `TYPE` enum in `@GlobalScope`.

If your value `o` is an instance of a class, `typeof(o)` will return `TYPE_OBJECT`.